# Ordering by FARM_FINGERPRINT is super slow in BigQuery with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pagination

I have a view that is based on, say, `table_1, table_2, table_3`:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  ...
  colN
FROM
  table1
LEFT JOIN
  table2
ON
  col1 = col2
```

This is the definition of my view that is queried.

The query itself is as follows:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
  colK,
  FARM_FINGERPRINT(col1 || col2 || ... || colK)

FROM
  my_view
ORDER BY
  FARM_FINGERPRINT(col1 || col2 || ... || colK)
LIMIT
  100
```

Let me explain why this is necessary in my case: querying this view is dynamic in that the user is supposed to specify the fields of interest. The tables are huge so without a `LIMIT` clause, the query is monstrously slow.

Pagination with `LIMIT/OFFSET`, however, is non-deterministic when no `ORDER BY` is specified. If I had a finite and constant set of fields, I could just use some default `ORDER BY` when no specific ordering is specified by the user.

This is why some additional column like a hash of column value is necessary to guarantee consistent results in the output.

The query with `FARM_FINGERPRINT` and ordering by this column is super slow and definitely is not an option for real use.

Is there any feasible alternative given that:

1. Implementing pagination with `LIMIT/OFFSET` is required
2. The set of columns in `SELECT` is dynamic and changes query to query

Comment: How are you interacting with BigQuery? Given that your user is specifying columns, are you using a client library? I ask because the client libraries support pagination/iteration, like this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#display_the_query_result

Comment: Yes, I am using a client library (Go)